# How can I pass the bash variable literally without any interpretation?

Tags: python, bash, parameters

I have a bash code as follows

```
python "$TM"
```

The problem is that $TM can be whatever character, including ` characters. When $TM has `abc`, the bash tries to run abc as a command before giving it a parameter to python.

How can I prevent this? How can I pass the $TM literally without any interpretation?

### ADDED

I need more explanation.

I'm using TextMate Bundle Editer so that the bash is called with a buffer ($TM_SELECTED_TEXT or $TM_CURRENT_LINE). The buffer is the selection I made in the TextMate editor. The bash code is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$TM_SELECTED_TEXT" ]; then
    TM="$TM_SELECTED_TEXT"
else

if [ -n "$TM_CURRENT_LINE" ]; then
    TM="$TM_CURRENT_LINE"
fi

fi

/usr/bin/python /Users/smcho/smcho/works/prgtask/textmate/repeat.py "$TM"
```

The repeat.py is as follows

```
import sys

inputString = sys.stdin.read().decode('utf-8')
inputString = inputString.rstrip().lstrip()

content = inputString[0:-2]
mark = inputString[-1]

r_num = len(content)
string = "%s\n%s" % (content, mark * r_num)
sys.stdout.write(string)
sys.exit(0)
```

If the input is "abc:-", it will convert the string to "abc\n---".

The problem is that if the input contains `` character, bash evaluates it before sending it to python code as parameter.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to pass the contents of the `TM` variable without any interpretation, not the literal 3-character string "$TM", right?

Comment: Odd. My bash doesn't expand backquotes in the result of variables, although its man page says that command substitution happens after parameter expansion.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `repeat.py`? There's nothing in the Bash script you've posted that could be the source of the problem.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson : I uploaded it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be conclusive, but add this line to your Bash script then look at the resulting file and post the result. `echo '$$' '$SHLVL' > /tmp/eval.out`

Comment: @Neil: it doesn't, they happen at the same time, from left to right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting it wrong. Bash didn't "expand" `TM` because it contained backticks (that would be a terrible security breach), the variable *already* contains the output of the command. You should quote the backticks to prevent the process substitution to occur:

```
$ TM="`ls`"
$ echo $TM
file1 file2
```

vs:

```
$ TM="\`ls\`" # or TM='`ls`'
$ echo $TM
`ls`
```

Comment: @tokland : The problem is that the $TM is just given to me. I elaborated the question.

Comment: Alternatively, use single quotes instead of double: '\`ls\`'

Comment: @prosseek: bash won't (shouldn't) run those backticks in a variable unless the whole thing is eval'ed again (is that the case?). Try then the already suggested "$TM".

Comment: @proseek: if the whole is eval'ed again, as it seems, quoting them won't help. You'll have to escape the string.

Comment: @tokland : That's the solution that I'm using now, I just wanted to check if I can make bash handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Why use bash as intermediary in the first place?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

tm = os.environ.get('TM_SELECTED_TEXT', "") or \
     os.environ.get('TM_CURRENT_LINE', "")
```

and so on…

Your repeat.py wouldn't do anything with that argument anyway.

Comment: 1125 upotes : 925 downvotes == 1:1.2 or 82% for down/up ratio. Highest I've seen if you weight it for total number of votes.

Comment: @SiegeX: i got that part, but how does that warrent a downvote on this answer?

Comment: @hop you'll have to ask the guy who down voted you about that. Not sure if that's visible info.

Comment: @SiegeX: sorry then, i thought that was you

Answer (score -2):

Your question is a bit vague but have you tried to see if quoting `$TM` to prevent word splitting solves your problem:

```
python "$TM"
```

Comment: @Thor it didn't at the time both myself and DigitalRoss answered.  See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5172644/revisions

Answer (score -2):

```
python "$TM"
```